# how to programtically capture authorized payments for orders during cron job for Drupal commerce

Tags: commerce

How to programatically capture authorized payments for orders during cron job for Drupal commerce .Payment gateway integrated is commerce stripe. Payment get authorized druing order placemnent and during cron job it need to be charged for all authorized payment for the orders. Drupal 10

Answer (score 0):

Commerce payment extra module can be used here is the link
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_payment_extra